# Unexpected behaviour of the program

Tags: c++

I need to perform following calculation based on the 2 input dates given in 'd m yyyy' format

```
1. if year_date1 > year_date2              // output 10000
2. else if month_date1 > month_date2       // output diff_month * 500
3. else if day_date1 > day_date2           // output diff_day * 15
4. else                                    // output 0
```

**e.g.**
Input-

```
2 7 1014         // date1
1 1 1015         // date2
```

Output

```
0
```

> But for same input case mentioned, why i am getting '3000' instead of a '0'?

**code**

```
int main(){    
    int dif_day,dif_month,dif_year;
    int day[2],month[2],year[2];

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
      cin >> day[i] >> month[i] >> year[i];

    dif_day = day[0] - day[1];
    dif_month = month[0] - month[1];
    dif_year = year[0] - year[1];

    if(dif_year > 0){
      cout << 10000;
    }
    else if(dif_month > 0){
      cout << dif_month * 500;
    }
    else if(dif_day > 0){
      cout << dif_day * 15;
    }
    else 
      cout << 0;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `diff_month` is `6`. Hence, your program executes `cout<<dif_month*500;`.

Comment: The automatic q-ban is affected by the count of your closed questions. Your this question was closed because it has not a question. Edit it to have a clear question, but so that the already posted answers won't be invalidated. After that, ping me (write a comment starting with @peterh...) and you will be good for a reopen vote (the reopen of your question will need 3, but also you can click "reopen" to your own closed questions). **Do this only after you fixed your question**, because the edit or the first reopen vote puts your question in the reopen review queue, and if it ends without

Comment: getting the misisng a reopen vote, then we will need to wait a month or more to start this again. | Your question looks now so: "I want this, here is my code, is it okay?" That is off-topic. But a question like this would be okay: "I want this, here is my minimal example, but it does not work because (explanation), what is the problem?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code subtracts the `year`, `month` and `date` and does some appropriate calculations.

In your example, `dif_year` is `-1`, and so the

```
if(dif_year > 0)
```

doesn't hold. Then the `dif_month` comes out to 6. The next condition is

```
if (dif_month > 0) // dif_month == 6
  cout << dif_month*500 // 6*500 = 3000
```

This explains the reason for the observed output.

Answer (score 0):

dif_year is not greater than 0 but -1 so then the program goes to the first else if statement where dif_month is greater than 0 (6) and executes 6 * 500 which is 3000 and which it outputs. The rest of the else statements are skipped.

To get 0, all numbers of the first date will have to be less than the numbers of the second date. For example, 1 1 1014 2 7 1015 will give you an output of 0.

The program's behavior is very much expected.